# Android - Debugging WebView with a JavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android

I looked around for similar questions which mentioned the "remote" debugging that the Chrome site provides: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

But I couldn't find something helpful for debugging when it comes to apps which have a specific interface for an embedded webpage. I imagine that remote debugging would fail pretty easily if the interface were missing.

I was hoping, essentially, for a way to forward errors from the Javascript console to LogCat. I have to use LogCat cause my app has @JavascriptInterface on some methods, and the JavaScript is too complicated for me to insert console.log() statements everywhere.